# Having problems to get correct properties with Find and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collections, model, find

I have these collections:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const TaskToDoSchema = Schema({

    equipo: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Equipo",
        autopopulate: {select: "codigo"}
    },
    tarea: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: "Task",
            autopopulate: {select: "tipotarea"}
        },
    encargado: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            autopopulate: {select: "name dni"}    
        },
    frecuencia: String
    
});
TaskToDoSchema.plugin(require("mongoose-autopopulate"));
module.exports = model("TaskToDo", TaskToDoSchema, "taskstodo");
```

```
const {Schema, model} = require("mongoose");

const TaskDoneSchema = Schema({
    tasktodo: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "TaskToDo",
        autopopulate: true
    },
    fechaDone: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }  
})
TaskDoneSchema.plugin(require("mongoose-autopopulate"));
module.exports = model("TaskDone", TaskDoneSchema, "tasksdone");
```

The first model defines a determined task that must be performed in a determined machine, by a determined person, all this info is taken from other collections.

The second model is used to define that a tasktodo is done, so I save a new record with the tasktodo Id and the date this task was performed.

I wish to list all the tasks done in a specific machine, by its ID, so, I defined this route:

```
router.get("/listbyequipo/:id", check.auth, TaskDoneController.listbyequipo);
```

where `check.auth` is an authentication middleware.

To perform the query I tried with:

```
const listbyequipo = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let equipo = req.params.id;
        let taskDone = await TaskDone.find({'tasktodo.equipo._id': equipo})
                                     .exec()
        console.log(taskDone)
        res.send({
            status:"Succes",
            message:"Consulta de registros exitosa",
            taskDone
        })
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({
            status: "Error",
            message: "Error al mostrar los registros"
        });
        next(error);
    }
}
```

But the result is an empty array.

I´m not sure where is the problem, I also tried defining `'tasktodo.equipo._id': mongoose.type.objectId(equipo)` but the problem persists.

Probably, this image can help to understand how levels are defined in the collection:

[image]

I have also tried this:

```
//Metodo para listar todas las tareas realizadas en un equipo especifico
const listbyequipo = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const id = (req.params.id);
        const query ={'tasktodo.equipo._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}
        console.log(id);
        let taskDone = await TaskDone.find({query})
                                    
        res.send({
            status:"Succes",
            message:"Consulta de registros exitosa",
            taskDone
        })
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({
            status: "Error",
            message: "Error al mostrar los registros"
        });
        next(error);
    }
}
```

But the result is a list with all the registers in the collection.